# Heroku process.env.port is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I am trying to run a node.js app on heroku. I got it working local, but when i deploy it on heroku i get the following error:

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

This is the port i try to listen to:

```
const PORT = process.env.port || 3000;
```

When i logged what the process.env.port was it said process.env.port was undefined.

Is there anything i need to do to automatically set the port?

Edit (FIX):
So i found out where the problem was. The javascript was being minified, but the process.env.port was minified to something that didn't work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think it should be `process.env.PORT`.

Comment: @Зелёный: I tried it with uppercase PORT and nothing has changed.

Comment: So look's like the `$PORT` variable is not defined.

Comment: @Зелёный: Yeah that is the problem, but i don't know how to define it.

Comment: Old question from me, but because it got some views i should explain what happend. My gulp or webpack i ran at that time stripped some variables by accident. So what @Зелёный is saying is the correct way.

Comment: The accepted answer here is definitely wrong: Heroku always sets `PORT` for web processes itself. We cannot, and should not attempt to, choose our own port on Heroku. med morad's answer is the closest to a correct answer, despite referencing `Port` instead of `port`. The solution is the same: you must use `PORT`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for any one get to that post.
first check if you are writing `process.env.PORT` correctly.
I was writing `.Port` and it took 4 hours of my life to figure out the error

Comment: I spent a whole day trying to work out what was wrong... capitalized PORT and fixed. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and found the solution to pass heroku dyno port variable to node start script.

If you have created a Procfile in your root directory of your project just open it.

If you haven't created a Procfile just go to root directory of your project and create a file called "Procfile". The file has no extension and it helps to heroku get the starter point of your application. More details about it: [The Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)

In [Node.JS Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#default-web-process-type) there isn't provided any example how should look like Procfile.

In my case, I'm using Typescript and my output directory of .js files is in /build directory in my project folder. and I'm assuming that you have the same situation. If not, just put your starter file's directory.

Procfile:

```
web: PORT=$PORT node ./build/index.js
```

Comment: I think I have the same issue. However, Ive added a `procfile` in my project root, next to the `package.json` file with the contents you've specified - but pointing to my main bundled js file (`dist/main.bundle.js`). This is still not working - when I log process.env in my main.(ts)js, I just get ` Process Env: {}`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using babel, do not use the babel plugin **babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables** in Heroku.
I think Heroku does not set the PORT variable when doing a deployment, so that's why you would get undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to leave this for anybody who was confused like me, you have to use

`process.env.PORT`

NOT

`process.env.$PORT`

Comment: Please add it to a comment.

Comment: I don't have enough rep.