# Heroku errors Node

Tags: express, heroku, get, fetch, throw

I am new to Heroku and I wanted to deploy my simple NodeJs app to Heroku but I am constantly getting errors.Everything in the screenshot below :
[image: Heroku logs]
and the app.js file's get and post rout below : [image][image: post route]

I added the rpm config vars, env variables but nothing is working

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku process.env.port is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39096995/heroku-process-env-port-is-undefined)

Comment: Are you still having trouble with this?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much everywhere other than on Windows, `process.env.port` is different from `process.env.PORT`.

Use the uppercase version:

```js
process.env.port
// => undefined
process.env.PORT
// => '12345'
```

Of course, I made 12345 up. Heroku will give you an arbitrary value that changes frequently.